# How to pause execution while JDialog is open

Tags: java, swing

How can I make my application pause when I open custom JDialog and after the dialog is closed to make continue again.

Comment: I think you need to further define "pause."  Do you mean that you want the UI to completely stop responding?  Do you mean that you want some other executing thread to pause?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply use:

```
setModal(true);
```

I usually call it from within the constructor of the `JDialog`.

See the Javadocs on `setModal(boolean)`.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)

That will cause execution to block on the current thread until the dialog box closes.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
setModalityType(Dialog.DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);
```

It is equivalent to `setModal(true)` and technically the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

See the constructor of [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)). You can set the **modality** of this dialog. Setting modal=true will pause your application. You can also use the method [setModal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)).

Comment: These comments/answers do not say where the code will pause.  That point can be important to know.