# Java - Closing JOptionPane upon task completion

Tags: java, dispose, joptionpane

I want a JOptionPane that has no buttons and is not able to be closed by the user to appear in the center of the screen relative to another component. Then I want to execute some other code, after which I will close the JOptionPane.

Here is what I have:

```
JOptionPane uploadPane = new JOptionPane("Uploading data...", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}, null);
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setTitle("Uploading");
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setContentPane(uploadPane);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);

// TODO: Upload data

dialog.dispose();
```

This code creates a JOptionPane in the top left corner of the screen that appears how I want to appear (aside from its location). However, it doesn't close.

When I get rid of the line:

```
dialog.setModal(true);
```

The JOptionPane is created in the location that it should be and does close as per the dispose command. However, for some reason it doesn't say anything on it. There is no message or icon aside from the title.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You're likely blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: How does it happen that the EDT gets blocked?

Comment: You can blocker EDT by executing a long running process or calling a blocking method or Thread.sleep for example

Answer (score 0):

[Check this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927364/how-to-pause-execution-while-jdialog-is-open).

If you set model to `true` in JDialog, the execution will stop as soon as the `JDialog` is set to be visible and the execution will wait until the dialog is closed.

But in your code, you have given `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`.

So your dialog cannot be closed which means **your application execution will wait forever**.

This means that,

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
```

and any following lines are not executed at all.

Comment: Alright so is there a way to show the uploadPane in the dialog without pausing execution?

Comment: You need to remove the `setModel(true)`, but if that's not displaying the content, then it's probably because you have blocked EDT as MadProgrammer has mentioned. Your code as it is now is not enough to say for certain.

Comment: Hmm, how does one block the EDT exactly? You're right, the code works when I just make a new class and test it there. I don't know what I am doing in the class that would cause this. I use invokeLater once to run the entire thing, and getting rid of that doesn't change anything.

Comment: The dialog will block comtinuatioin of the execution of the  current code branch when the dialog is made visib

Comment: Why does making a dialog visible block the execution of the code? Is there any way I can have this dialog be visible without blocking execution?